# Reroute to users show page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

When I create an event on the users show page I want it to redirect back to the users show page if it indeed submitted correctly. Is there anyway I can do that here is my Events controller:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
    def show
      @event = Event.find(params[:id])
      @songs = @event.songs.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end

    def create
        @event = current_user.events.build(event_params)
        if @event.save
            flash[:success] = "Event Created!"
            redirect_to 'user#show'
        else
            render 'welcome#index'
        end
    end

    def destroy
    end

    private 

      def event_params
        params.require(:event).permit(:name, :partycode)
      end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redirect to the user path and pass in the User ID.

```
redirect_to user_path(current_user.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can, but you'll need to use the actual path eg instead of `redirect_to 'user#show'` user:

```
redirect_to user_path(@event.user)
```